# SFTP Persistent Accept Only Once filter on sftp gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I have this code in which I want to incorporate a SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter and I don't know how. The filter should be before retrieving files locally.

```
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "sftpMgetInputChannel",
    poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
public String filesForMGET(){
  return "'/tmp/input/remoteDirectory/*'";
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpMGetFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("sftpMgetInputChannel")
            .handleWithAdapter(h -> h.sftpGateway(this.sftpSessionFactory,
             Command.MGET, "payload")
            .options(Option.RECURSIVE)
            .regexFileNameFilter("((\\d{8})|*\\.txt)")
            .localDirectoryExpression("'sftp-inbound/'" + "#remoteDirectory"))
            .handler(messageHandler())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel sftpMgetInboundChannel(){
   return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public MessageHandler messageHandler(){
 return new MessageHandler() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CompositeFileListFilter` or `ChainFileListFilter` with a `SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter` filter and the `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`.

Construct the filter and use `.filter(compositeFilter())`.

Comment: The prefix ctor arg in the filter is simply to allow the use of the same store in multiple filters, for isolation.